# Polynomial of prime degree: being irreducible or having a root!

Tags: field-theory, roots, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $p$ be a prime number. Prove that for any field $K$ and any $a \in K$, the
>   polynomial $x^p−a$ is either irreducible, or has a root.

it doesn't seem hard, but i have no idea.

any hint is welcomed!

thank you

Comment: Its actually quite simple, although no one has stated it. A proper divisor of $x^p-a$ must have a constant term of the form $\zeta^i(\sqrt[p]{a})^k$ now by taking an appropriate power you get a root in $K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a duplicate, and has already been asked (and answered) several times:

[Prove $f=x^p-a$ either irreducible or has a root. (arbitrary characteristic) (without using the field norm)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460931/prove-f-xp-a-either-irreducible-or-has-a-root-arbitrary-characteristic-wi)

[Irreducibility of a polynomial if it has no root (Capelli)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266171/irreducibility-of-polynomial-if-no-root-capelli)

[$x^p-c$ has no root in a field $F$ if and only if $x^p-c$ is irreducible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403924/xp-c-has-no-root-in-a-field-f-if-and-only-if-xp-c-is-irreducible)

Comment: This is not an answer. You can post all these links as a comment.

Comment: You're right. But you need to have 50 rep to make a comment to a question, which I didn't have at the time.