# $f=X^p-a\in F[X]$ is irreducible iff $f$ has no root in $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be a field, $a$ an element of $F$ and $p$ prime.
How do I prove that

> $f=X^p-a\in F[X]$ is irreducible iff $f$ has no root in $F$?

Honestly, I have no idea how to approach this. Maybe somebody can give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: Notice that one direction is easy : irreducible $\implies$ no root (in $F$).

Comment: Related : [Prove $f=x^p-a$ either irreducible or has a root](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460931/prove-f-xp-a-either-irreducible-or-has-a-root-arbitrary-characteristic-wi?rq=1)

Comment: Also note that this depends on $p$ being prime.  For example, $X^4+1$ has no root in $\mathbb{R}$, but it is reducible.